# What is the difference between parallel and CMS garbage collection

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am new to GC and have been to trying to understand by reading different articles. The more I read , I am getting more confused. I am having a hard time understand the difference between parallel and cms GC. 
some articles says " **the parallel uses multiple GC threads, while the CMS uses only one**." and some say "`CMS uses multiple threads (“concurrent”) to scan through the heap (“mark”) for unused objects that can be recycled (“sweep”)"` ? Can someone please explain me in simple words?. `And what is initial mark, remark, concurrent mark and sweeping phase in CMS`?